# Drag and drop between CStatic controls in MFC dialog

Tags: mfc, drag-and-drop

I have an MFC dialog with several 'source' CStatic controls and a single 'target' CStatic control. I want to be able to drag from any source to the target, and process the drop event. I create all of the controls programatically.

I realize I probably want to derive specialized CSource and CTarget objects from CStatic. How exactly can I do that? What has to be done in the derived controls, or in the dialog, to make this work? Note this is a dialog, not an SDI or MDI.

You can think of the sources as items and the target as a cart, so the user would be dragging items into the cart. There is nothing more than that. I will process the drop event to represent what was just dropped. Nothing more needs to be done graphically. I just need to be able to get the events.

Are there any examples out there for implementing this behavior?

Comment: Documentation (including sample code) available at [Drag and Drop (OLE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/drag-and-drop-ole).

Comment: @IInspectable : Thanks -- already found that via google, but not helpful. No useful code sample for a simple drag between simple controls exists for a dialog-based app as far as I can see. This can't be rocket science, but it seems completely undocumented.